# CSS Formatting on Wordpress Menu Class

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I have the following formatting on my horizontal WordPress menu. It works great.

```
.menu {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  list-style: none;
}
```

In the footer of my theme I am trying to use a vertical menu through the WordPress menu setup.  When I put the menu in the footer via a widget I get this:

```
<div class="menu-footer-container"><ul id="menu-footer" class="menu">
```

Because the UL class is menu it picks up the above horizontal css and makes the menu horizontal in my footer.  How do I add CSS to make the menu vertical in my WordPress footer?

Comment: A result of this can help us to find a solution for you.

Comment: @user1609391 if my answer helped you please consider marking my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="menu-footer" class="menu-ver">
```

You can use a different class for example `menu-ver` having following CSS,

```
.menu-ver {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu-ver li{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also you can adjust the margin property according to your design if you don't want it to get centered.

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu-footer-container .menu li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Use this code and it will work nicely. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem it's on the `.menu` class, I'm assuming the problem it's in a CSS style for your `li` tags somewhere on your stylesheet.

It should look something like this: `.menu li {display:inline-block;}`. You can fix this by giving a style only for the `li` tags for your footer like this:

```
#menu-footer li {
    display: list-item;
}
```

Check out this [online example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7awty3a/)

---

Anyways if you still wanna style the `.menu` class just for the footer, you can do it like this:

`.menu-footer-container .menu { ... }` or simply style `#menu-footer { ... }` with the desired results.